# jquery and masonry page resize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-masonry

So all was working fine until something went wrong, all the images are fine when page loads but on a window resize the images don't stack and there's holes in the image stack on the page. Here's the code.

## js.coffeee file

```
$ ->
  $('#pins').imagesLoaded ->
    $('#pins').masonry
      itemSelector: '.box'
      isFitWidth: true
```

## `css file

```
#pins {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.box {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 214px;
}

.box img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

## application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require masonry/jquery.masonry
//= require_tree .
```